# when i'm trying to update, iam getting error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: remi-php74

Tags: repository, yum

```
[root@internalcrm ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: etckeeper, fastestmirror, merge-conf
Repository 'remi-php74' is missing name in configuration, using id
Repository 'remi-php80' is missing name in configuration, using id
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
   upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
   distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
   packages for the previous distribution release still work).
3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
   yum --disablerepo= ...
4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
   will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
   again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

   `yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>`

or

```
subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>
```

5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
   Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
   so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
   slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
   compromise:

`yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true`

`Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: remi-php74`

Comment: For a proper configuration, follow the Wizard instructions:
https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/